# My CPU is overheating after unparking my CPU cores

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cooling, overheating

I used a program called "CoreParkingManager" and by default it was set to 5%. I wanted to try it out, and set it to 80% and it actually improved my FPS in games, but the CPU was overheating, so I was changing it back to 5% after I stop playing.

I have noticed that my CPU started overheating even when I don't play games, even though I have set it to 5%, it uses more power than it used before. I'm not sure what I did wrong, or maybe the program did something because it's in beta, but I'd like to know how to properly park my cores again so my CPU stop the overheating.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your CPU shouldnt be overheating period; softeare shoudl not overheat a CPU

Comment: @Ramhound Well, in this case, the software also modifies the way hardware works... so it applies.

Comment: Yes; but a CPU is designed to run at 100% so you have a cooling problem; you are not doing anything the CPU can't handle

Comment: Check the CPU usage if there's some process that use it. Eventually uninstall the beta program, reboot and check if the problem remail. PS>Check if the fans work properly and if the air can flow free of obstacles... BTW how long the CPU was overheated?

Comment: The CPU works fine, there are no processes which overheat it, I'm running only Chrome + Steam, no games or anything else like that. This started happening 3 days ago, I'm not exactly sure why. I have a laptop btw. And the cooler is not the problem I'm 99% sure because the overheating happens from time to time randomly. Uninstalling the program wouldn't do anything, because it doesn't require installation in first place, it's just a simple .exe file which allows you to change the core parking.

Comment: Benchmark your computer; if it happens; then you have a cooling problem; but you do have a hardware problem.

Comment: @Ramhound It has been calm for 10+ hours so far, I doubt this is a hardware problem. But sometimes it happens at random times for unknown reason, which I believe was caused by this.

Comment: What has been running for 10 hours exactly?  Unless you are talking about a benchmark that pushes your CPU to work at 100% then you cannot rule out a cooling problem..  A CPU should not at its default stock settings crash, when its its pushed to 100%, a CPU is designed to run at 100% and not crash.  I don't care if its a tablet, phone, laptop, server, desktop product.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, the problem is that I don't want to push it to 100%, I've had it set by default 5% when I bought the laptop, factory settings, and I used to boost it with this program, but when I remove the boost, it seems to not remove it, maybe a bug in the program which still allows the CPU to go beyond the numbers I have set it not to. That's the problem.

Comment: If you don't want to attempt my diagnostic troubleshooting then I can't help you.  The software does not do anything the hardware can't handle.  So if your computer is overheating from just parking the cores at 80% then you have a cooling problem.